# como usar un dato nulo para un if

Tags: javascript, ajax, condiciones, null

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con notificaciones ya tengo mi api para obtener el usuario y otro para enviar la notificación. llamo a mi api que obtiene la información

```
$.ajax({
   url: ua,
   type: 'GET',
   async: false,
   cache: false,
   success: function (respuesta) {
   //console.log(respuesta);
   A_correo_electronico = respuesta.correo_electronico;
   A_nombre_completo = respuesta.nombre_completo;
   console.log('prueba',A_correo_electronico);
   },
   error: function (respuesta) {
   console.log('fallo obtenerUsuarioSesion');
   }
   });
```

esta api obtiene el nombre y correo electrónico de los usuarios que tienen cierto puesto, pero si no hay nadie que tenga el puesto (por ejemplo maestro) me devuelve algo vacío o indefinido

entonces seria

```
if(A_correo_electronico  != ´´){
$.messager.alert('Gestión inscripción ','inscripción realizada se procederá a notificar a director y a maestro','info');
}else{
$.messager.alert('Gestión inscripción ','inscripción realizada se procederá a notificar a director','info');
}
```

también lo he intentado

```
if(A_correo_electronico  != ´undefined´){
$.messager.alert('Gestión inscripción ','inscripción realizada se procederá a notificar a director y a maestro','info');
}else{
$.messager.alert('Gestión inscripción ','inscripción realizada se procederá a notificar a director','info');
}
```

pero siempre ingresa al if de notificación a maestro y director aunque no exista un director  por lo que después colapsa mi código al no haber nadie de director

Answer (score 2):

Puede ser de esta manera:

```js
// Si esta indefinido entra. 
if (!A_correo_electronico) {
  $.messager.alert('Gestión inscripción ', 'inscripción realizada se procederá a notificar a director y a maestro', 'info');
} else {
  $.messager.alert('Gestión inscripción ', 'inscripción realizada se procederá a notificar a director', 'info');
}
```

## [Operador lógico not `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_l%C3%B3gicos)

> Devuelve false si su único operando se puede convertir a true; de lo contrario, devuelve true

Ejemplos:

```js
var n1 = !true;  // !t devuelve false 
console.log(n1)
var n2 = !false; // !f devuelve true  
console.log(n2)
var n3 = !'Cat'; // !t devuelve false 
console.log(n3)
var n4 = !undefined; // !t devuelve true 
console.log(n4)
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió la primera forma